# Adding Spinner Function inside Jquery onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I have the following code.

```
----HTML Part---
<div id="Optimize" class="Div"> Optimize </div>


 ----Jquery Part---
$('#Optimize').click(function()
{  

var form_data = new FormData();  
form_data.append('action',"Opt");
var perlURL= "$code"; 

$.ajax({        
        url:    perlURL,
        data:   form_data,
        type: 'post',
        datatype: "script",
        success: function(result) {
        },

        });        
});
```

Once the user clicks on Optimization, the following jquery code will execute and display results to user. Now i need to insert a Spinner whenever user clicks Optimization to show that data is loading. Once data gets loaded, spinner should stop. So i have the two functions. If i insert those 2 functions, the Jquery code will look like this.

```
$('#Optimize').click(function()
{  
startSpin(); // ------------------------START SPIN HERE----------------
var form_data = new FormData();  
form_data.append('action',"Opt");
var perlURL= "$this_code"; 

$.ajax({        
        url:    perlURL,
        data:   form_data,
        type: 'post',
        datatype: "script",
        success: function(result) {
        stopSpin(); // --------------STOP SPIN HERE --------------
        },

});
```

This code should work as expected. i.e. spinner should start as soon as user clicks on "Optimize". but it doesnot start. i get a feeling that it straight away performs execution in asynchronous manner.

How can i ensure that the user executes startSpin(); first and then the later part of the function ?

I have read about promise() and have tried various ways to perform both functions simultaneously. but couldnt succeed.

Comment: Is `async: false` intended?

Comment: Is it possible that the data is being returned too quickly to notice the animation?

Comment: @JackPattishall- updated the code. async:false has been removed.

Comment: @AntonioDangond- I see a 2 sec delay. the screen freezes and after tat it displays the data. so the data returned is not quick

Comment: When `startSpin()` is called do you see the animation at all? The problem could be in there.

Comment: Instead of using startSpin and stopSpin functions everywhere that is to happen, you could hook onto the ajaxStart and ajaxStop global events https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: @stett- I removed the stopSpin() and added my startSpin() there. The startSpin() started spinning once the data gets loaded. It means startSpin() works...

Comment: @Ixonal- I tried ajaxStart. It starts spinning just before ajax is called. and as soon as ajax is called data is displayed. the actual gap of time occurs when user clicks on "Optimize" using onclick.

Comment: @Ayesha I'm confused. Shouldn't the ajax call be made after the user clicks optimize? If things are happening in the order you specify, there must be another ajax request happening somewhere.

Comment: @Ixonal- thats what confuses me too. believe me, there are no other ajax calls. just this ajax call. and ajax call is made only when user clicks "Optimize".

Comment: @Ayesha What does your network traffic look like? is the ajax call succeeding?

Comment: @Ixonal- AJAX call shows successful. however i used a debug point to see what the flow is when user clicks on "Optimize". The first line of Jquery gets executed. i.e. $('#Optimize').click(function() and then straight away jumps to the last line of the function. It then goes to jquery plugin and performs some functions there and then it comes back to showing the ajax data

Comment: @Ayesha I can't think of a way for the engine to skip over execution of some code and then start executing the skipped code again after it (which is what it sounds like it's doing by your description). I have no clue what's going on then...

Comment: @Ixonal- is there a way to use onclick() in the html part itself and then show two functions there. ?? so it will execute both the functions individually ??

Comment: @Ayesha I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @Ixonal- instead of above html code, can we try like this...<div onclick= "Optimize();startSpin();" class="Div"> Optimize </div> or something like this... i tried but didnt work out... can you suggest a few other steps like this so i can try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will surely help someone. I tried using the bind function in jquery and tried to bind both the functions to the onclick event. it was unsuccessful.

However after several retries, i thought of using the jquery function inside a javascript function. So now both the functions are plain javascript functions. I did the following.

```
-----------HTML CODE-------------
----------START SPIN HERE------------
<div class="Div" onclick="startSpin();setTimeout(function() { runopt(); }, 100);  " > Run Optimization </div>


-----------SCRIPT CODE-------------
<script type="text/javascript">
function runopt() {

//$('#Optimize').click(function()
// {  

var form_data = new FormData();  
form_data.append('action',"Opt");
var perlURL= "$code"; 

$.ajax({        
      url:    perlURL,
      data:   form_data,
      type: 'post',
      datatype: "script",
      success: function(result) {
      },

});  
stopSpin();  // -----------------STOP SPIN HERE -----------------  
// });
}
```

Commented out values in the script means earlier code. I have used both the functions at html side onclick and delayed the second function by 100 msec. it did the trick. the first function was allowed to run and then the second function { runopt() } was run.